# Symfony2 validation getters error for a specific field

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I'm using [Symfony2 validation getters](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/validation.html#getters) to validate if `endDate` is later than startDate. It works fine except that I want the error to appear for `endDate` field not above the whole form. All other validation errors appears above the field it validates. Is there any way to do that?

validation part in my Entity:

```
/**
 * @Assert\True(message = "Invalid date")
 */
public function isDatesValid()
{
    return ($this->startDate < $this->endDate);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to achieve that with a getter validation.

Instead you could use a custom constraint: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html

You'll need to overide the *getTargets()* method in order to access all properties:

```
class DateRangeConstraint extends Constraint {

    public $message = 'Your message';

    public function getTargets() {
        return Constraint::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }
}

class DateRangeConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator {

     public function validate($obj, Constraint $constraint) {
         if ($obj->startDate() < $obj->endDate()) {
             $this->context->addViolationAt(
                'startDate',
                 $constraint->message,
                array(),
                null
         );
    }
}
```

}

Assign this constraint to one or both properties.